# How can I maintain a Xamarin Forms control's aspect ratio in a StackLayout

Tags: c#, user-interface, layout, xamarin.forms

I have a [SkiaSharp view which is embedded in a Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/integration) app. The SkiaSharp view needs to be drawn at a particular aspect ratio. The view's width depends on its parent (and phone size/idiom), so the width is not always known when the view is first created, therefore I can't set a [HeightRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.HeightRequest?view=xamarin-forms) when the view is first constructed.

I can't use a [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout) because I need to have the SkiaSharp view in a [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout) with more controls sitting under the view. Plus, I'm looking for a more general solution where I can place the SkiaSharp view in any layout object like a grid.

Is there a way for me to specify an aspect ratio for the SkiaSharp view and have it automatically size its height based on a desired aspect ratio and its width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the width of the view cannot be determined when it is first created, the code must react to the width changing and setting the HeightRequest at that time.

```
// If you want to dynamically adjust the aspect ratio after creation
// this property should have logic in its setter to adjust the height request
public float DesiredAspectRatio { get; set; }

public MyControl()
{
   // Subscribe to the SizeChanged event in the constructor
   SizeChanged += HandleSizeChanged;
}

private void HandleSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.Width > 0 && desiredAspectRatio > 0)
   {
       var desiredHeightRequest = this.Width / DesiredAspectRatio;
       // int it to make sure there's no weird recursive behavior
       // caused in release by how floats/doubles are handled.
       if((int)desiredHeightRequest != (int)HeightRequest)
       {
           this.HeightRequest = (int)desiredHeightRequest;
           InvalidateMeasure();
       }
   }
}
```

I'm not certain if `InvalidateMeasure` is necessary, but the code above worked for me.